# How to remove id in url

Tags: javascript, php, html

now i face a problem with user will see the popout with "update sucessfully" if he reload the page or backward to the page.Anyone having idea of how to remove ?id=2 after click ok on pop out?
Here is my code:

update_action.php

```
$updresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlu);

    if (!$updresult)
        echo "Unable to update record". mysqli_error($conn);
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php?id=2' );
        mysqli_close($conn);
    } 
    ?>
```

index.php

```
if ($id == 1) 
    {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert("Invalid user name or password, Try again");
        </script>
    <?php   
    }
        else if($error_id == 2)
    {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert("Update Sucessfully!"); 
        </script>
    <?php
    }
```

[the url show index.php?id=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTdFW.png)

Comment: Are you using the browser default alert

Comment: im not using browser default alert,may I know how to use default alert?

Comment: what i want is just pop out "update sucessfully" one time on the browser.no matter using what method

Comment: Try using sweet alerts in which you can add functions on button click. Here is the place you can remove your query string( ' ?id=1 ' ).

Comment: Change the `alert()` to `confirm()`. That way you can get a boolean if the user has clicked okay or cancel. You can look at the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($id == 1) 
{
?>
    <script>
        alert("Invalid user name or password, Try again");
    </script>
<?php   
}
    else if($error_id == 2)
{
?>
    <script>
        alert("Update Sucessfully!"); 
 //---------- added ---------------
        window.location.href= 'index.php';
 //-------------------------

    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: thank! It work! I forgot (window.location.href) this code.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change the url with javascript without reloading the page.

Check out: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/History/pushState

You can put this after your alert/confirm

```
// Remove the "?.." from the url
var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
// maybe check if the browser supports history.pushState
history.pushState({}, '', url);
```

Comment: thankyou for help me,this method are complicated for me.I found a easy way to make it,btw,thankyou